# How do I keep and update a persistent variable in a sinatra app on heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I have a very small sinatra app. it basically redirects to google search. I deployed it on heroku.I wanted to track the amounts of hits it got, so I added a "hits" variable and had it update every time the page was loaded.
The problem I am facing is that every time I push a new release, the app reboots and the variable resets (which is not surprising, really).

Is there a way to keep a variable persistently? and update it as required? Can the heroku env_vars do that?

I was thinking about a local file store as a solution but that file would also be over written every time a new change is pushed. Do you guys have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: why don't you simply add a Google Analytics tracker?

Comment: Because all i want to do is show the people visiting the site how many people have already visited. I have no need to track any other thing. :)
I fixed it with a simple database transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no way to use heroku ENV vars for this. To do this, I created a simple database table that keeps track of all the information.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a database just for this you might want to consider just writing to a text file as a CSV, or even using the built in [ruby logger method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html).